# C# - passing arguments with space in between them to a process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass an argument to a process a folder with space in its name. It doesn't recognize the folder. How can i do that?

```
string my_arg = @"C:\\program files\\my folder with spaces";

ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();

proc.FileName = @"C:\batches\my_batch.bat";

proc.Arguments = @my_arg ;

Process.Start(proc);
```

the process wont start - it does work if i use a folder with no spaces in the name.
Thank you!

Comment: Try encoding my_arg with extra quotation marks around it, like my_arg = "\"" + my_arg + "\"";. Would that work?

Answer (score 7):

You’re using literal strings; there is no need to escape the backslashes, and indeed if you do then there’s no need to use a literal string in the first place.

The spaces on the other hand require special care – encase the argument into quotes solves this.

```
string my_arg = @"""C:\program files\my folder with spaces""";
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
string my_arg = "\"C:\\program files\\my folder with spaces\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following as foldernames with spaces should be quoted in cmd:

```
string my_arg = @"""C:\\program files\\my folder with spaces""";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

string my_arg = @"\"C:\program files\my folder with spaces\|";

ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();

proc.FileName = @"C:\batches\my_batch.bat";

proc.Arguments = @my_arg ;

Process.Start(proc);